# waitForSelector Timing Out

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am having a problem using CasperJS. Basically, here are the steps I want to go through:

1. Go to loginUrl
2. Fill in the login form with the correct username and password
3. Submit the login form
4. Wait until the right selector is on the page, and then take a screenshot of the page.

Here is my setup for Steps 1 through 3. (I capture an image here to make sure that I am able to log into the website);

**Steps 1 through 3 (plus screenshot):**

```
var env = require('system').env;
var casper = require('casper').create();


var loginUrl = env.loginUrl;
var login = env.login;
var password = env.password;


casper.on('remote.message', function(event) { // log messages from browser
  console.log(event);
});


casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36'); // set user agent


casper.start(loginUrl); // open the following url


casper.then(function() { // login
  this.fill('#form_signin', {username: login, password: password}, true);
});

casper.wait(2000, function() {
  this.capture('./output/test.png');
});


casper.run();
```

The above works well. The image that is captured is exactly what I was expecting. However, I don't want to use a **wait** - instead, I'd like to use a **waitForSelector**. I replace by **wait** function above with this:

```
casper.waitForSelector('#attendance', function() {
  this.capture('./output/test.png');
})
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. At first I though that it might be because the selector is wrong. *However, when I log into the site manually, with Chrome, and I run document.getElementById("attendance") I get the expected element back.*

I thought I might have better luck if I tried searching for the selector in the context of the page itself, so instead of replacing **wait** with **waitForSelector**, I replaced it with this:

```
function attendanceCheck() {
  return this.evaluate(function() {
    return !!document.getElementById('attendance');
  });
}


casper.waitFor(attendanceCheck, function() {
  this.capture('./output/test.png');
})
```

Even with this setup, I was getting a timeout, meaning that **attendanceCheck** was never able to find an element that fits the given selector, even when evaluating in the context of the page.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I know that I can log in, and I know that, once the entire page loads, there is an element with an id of "attendance", yet **waitForSelector** and **waitFor** are not able to find this element. (Eventually, I have to click this element, so I have to be able to find it).

Comment: You can pass a function as a third argument to `waitForSelector` which will be called when the timeout happens. Take a screenshot and print the page source and then look for the element you're expecting. Do you see it? Is the element maybe in an iframe?

Comment: Artjom - thank you for the response. I passed a third argument to waitForSelector to capture a screenshot, and I still see the expected page. That being said, I also saw this on the debugger:  Navigation requested: url=[REDACTED], type=Other, willNavigate=true, isMainFrame=false - the isMainFrame false leads to believe maybe an iFrame is being loaded. How can I check for that, and how can I print / save the source?

Comment: You can save the page in this way: `require(fs).write("page.html", casper.getHTML());`. If you don't see your intended element, but instead see an iframe, you need to switch to the frame using `casper.withFrame` first, before waiting.